# Assigning reader results to multiple objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I'm trying to get data from a database and return it as `JSON` for a web service. I can return the data no problem but it seems to be only return data for the first row and not the rest. I'm using `SqlReader` and my code is something like:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string EvidenceLink()
{
    var rootObject = new List<RootObject>();
    var root = new RootObject();
    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C FROM MYTABLE";


    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    root = new RootObject
                    {
                        children = new List<Child>
                        {
                            new Child
                            {
                                name = reader["COLUMN A"].ToString(),
                                children = new List<Child2> 
                                {
                                    new Child2
                                    {
                                        name = reader["COLUMN B"].ToString(),
                                        parent = reader["COLUMN A"].ToString(),
                                        children = new List<GrandChild> 
                                        {
                                            new GrandChild 
                                            {
                                                name = reader["COLUMN C"].ToString(),
                                                parent = reader["COLUMN B"].ToString(),
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    root.name = "ParentRoot";
                    root.parent = "null";
                    rootObject.Add(root);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var strJSON = js.Serialize(rootObject);
    return strJSON;
}
```

I have 5 rows in my database and what I'm trying to achieve is the first row goes to one `Child Object` and another one to next `Child Object` and so on. I can't seem to figure out why it's only returning the first row from the database and not the rest.

This is the `JSON` I'm trying to produce

```
{
"name": "Root",
"parent": "null",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "First Child",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Inner Child",
                "parent": "First Child",
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Second Child",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Inner Child",
                "parent": "Second Child",
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Third Child",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Inner Child",
                "parent": "Third Child",
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My structure is as follows:

```
public class GrandChild
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string parent { get; set; }
}

public class Child2
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string parent { get; set; }
public List<GrandChild> children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
public string name { get; set; }
public List<Child2> children { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string parent { get; set; }
public List<Child> children { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Any exceptions? Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: You are creating a new root object every time the `while` loop continues.. just use `root.children.Add()` or something instead.. otherwise the content is overwritten each time..

Comment: @JanUnld Can you show me a sample code snippet please of what you mean

Comment: Is the reader returning all 5 lines for certain?

Comment: @CallumBradbury yes I've debugged it and I can see it's returning all 5 lines of the DB

Comment: Jan, whilst it may appear that's what he's doing, I don't believe that's the case. He creates a new root, then adds it to his list of rootObject, nothing should be overwritten, he just has awful variable names that confuse the matter.

Edit: Based on my reading of it, the list rootObject should contain 5 RootObject instances, each with a maximum of 1 child & 1 grandchild. If the intent is to have a single root object then the list is redundant and Jan is correct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No exceptions and I've debugged the code and I can see 5 records

Comment: When stepping through the code, what do you see when examining the rootObject variable? Does each `root` get added to `rootObject`?

Comment: @CallumBradbury ye you're right. i messed up.. but that whole thing seems kinda not pretty usable. what exactly is your aim @Code? Edit: You'd have to fetch all the data first to reflect it to something like you want thought..

Comment: @Ulric each of the `root` gets added to the `rootObject`

Comment: @JanUnld I'm trying to return it as JSON so I can use it on a graph which is populated using `d3js`

Comment: @Code - Ok. Does the `rootObject.Count()` increase as expected with each addition? If so, at what point does the `rootObject` lose 4 of the roots?

Comment: What's about the line `root.name = "ParentRoot"`. All your roots inside your "master" root object list does get the same name does that overwrite something?
What's the structure for the type `RootObject`? A "root" is usually unique..

Comment: @JanUnld If I don't use `root.name` then all object lists get null whilst debugging

Comment: try using something like `root.name = String.Format("ParentRoot{0}", rootObject.Count())`

Comment: @JanUnld I've just formatted the `JSON` and the `ParentRoot` goes up to 4.. but I want only one `ParentRoot` and the rest child

Comment: @JanUnld See my updated question, I have pasted the JSON which I am trying to produce

Comment: @CallumBradbury I just read your edit in the comment, I am trying to achieve a list with one root object and multiple child within it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright let's just try..

```
var rootNode = new RootObject();
rootNode.name = null;
rootNode.parent = null;
rootNode.children = new List<RootParent>();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...", connection)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        rootNode.name = (string) reader["COLUMN A"];
        while (reader.Read()) {
            var parentNode = new RootParent();
            parentNode.name = (string) reader["COLUMN B"];
            parentNode.children = new ParentChild[] {
                new ParentChild {
                    name = (string) reader["COLUMN C"],
                    parent = (string) reader["COLUMN B"],
                    children = null
                };
            };
            rootNode.children.Add(parentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Requirements for this implementation to work:

```
public class RootObject {
    public string name;
    public string parent;
    public List<RootParent> children;
}

public class RootParent {
    public string name;
    public List<ParentChild> children;
}

public class ParentChild {
    public string name;
    public string parent;
    public List<object> children;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

<strike>Note that you have to return the `RootObject root`. According to the attribute parameter `ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json` the response should be converted/serialized automatically.</strike>

<strike>What type of web project are you using to implement your logic?</strike>

<strike>Forgot to add the `parentNode` to the `root` instance. Make sure to add the line `rootNode.children.Add(parentNode);` ..</strike>

Updated section above..

Comment: If don't use `Serialize` then I don't get JSON back instead get an XML format. I'm using `WebForms` and with your code I'm still getting similar results to before. I get 5 `Root Objects` and what I'm looking for is, 1 RootObject with multiple `Child Objects`

Comment: I just added the `rootNode.children.Add(parentNode);` and I get the following errors: `Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Child>.Add(Child)' has some invalid arguments` and `Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'RootObject' to 'Child'`

Comment: alright. thought you're using the types as some synonyms.. guess they are real. can you please give some more code then.. the structure for the types `RootObject`, `Child`, `Child2` and `GrandChild` would be great..

Comment: That makes a little more sense, however I'm getting a error again `Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ParentChild[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ParentChild>'`

Comment: Have you ever worked with collections before? O.O Just cast the array to list or change the type from `ParentChild[]` to `List<ParentChild>`

Comment: I have but to a very basic level

Comment: You're a life saver.. it works as expected! Thanks alot